# Homotopy between representations of compact group

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a compact group, and $\rho_1, \rho_2 : G\rightarrow GL(V)$ two finite-dimensional representations. Let $H:G\times[0,1] \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a homotopy of continuous functions, means:

- $\forall g \in G, H(g,0)=\rho_1 (g),H(g,1)=\rho_2 (g)$
- H is continuous
- for every $t\in [0,1]$, the function $H_t:(g,v)\mapsto H(g,v,t)$ is a representation

I'm trying to show that $\rho_1 \cong \rho_2$ as G-representations.

We know that if $G$ is compact, so all the finite-dimensional G-representations are semi-simple, so simply by induction it's enough to prove for irreducible representations (is it so? I'm not even sure it works in compact group...). But I can't even see why assuming the reps. are irreducible would help.

Comment: compose it with the trace on $GL(V)$ to get the $t$-dependent character, compute its inner product with an  irreducible character, the result is an integer which depends continuously on $t$, so it is a constant